# Unity как импортировать библиотеку из Visual Studio

Tags: c#, unity3d, backend, aerospike

Ребята заранее извиняюсь за вопрос... но для меня на данном этапе изучения очень непростой.

Столкнулся с проблемой при реализации клиента на Unity c бекендом на Aerospike.
Установил необходимую библиотеку в Microsoft Visual Studio но запустить проект в Unity не получается.

в Microsoft Visual Studio установил одной командой

```
Install-Package Aerospike.Client
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно импортировать необходимые библиотеки из Visual Studio в Unity чтобы все заработало. Cсылка на библиотеки - компоненты [Aerospike](https://developer.aerospike.com/client/csharp/install)

Comment: так как юнити сама собирает код, установка пакетов в студии ничего не меняет для юнити. Насколько я знаю, нужно скачать dll и закинуть её в юнити в ассеты

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53447595/nuget-packages-in-unity

Comment: @iKuzmychov - шикарная ссылка! Спасибо! (если что - я не автор вопроса, просто мимокрокодил). Не хотите немного перевести и оформить, как ответ?

Comment: @S.H. ну раз вы настаиваете)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ссылаясь на ответы на [похожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53447595/nuget-packages-in-unity) с англоязычной ветки [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com):

1. Вы можете использовать NuGet-клиент для Unity, для установки пакетов из NuGet в Unity без головной боли. Инструкцию по установке и использованию, как и релиз, можно найти в [GitHub-репозитории проекта](https://github.com/GlitchEnzo/NuGetForUnity).
2. Другой вариант использования NuGet-пакета в Unity - выполнить следующие шаги:

- перейдите на нужную веб-страницу пакета NuGet;
- справа выберите `Загрузить пакет`;
- поменяйте расширение скачаного файла с `.nupkg` пакета на `.zip`
- перейдите в `lib` и скопируйте dll-файл пакета из любой папки `net` или `netstandard`;
- откройте рабочее пространство Unity и создайте папку `Plugin`;
- вставьте туда скопированный dll-файл.

Comment: Бесконечная благодарность!